# Get output from Python script in QT

Tags: python, c++, qt, output, qprocess

I want to run script written in Python and get all output from that.
This is my cpp code

```
QProcess process;
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
QString exe = "python script.py";
process.start(exe);
process.waitForFinished(-1);
QString output(process.readAllStandardOutput());

qDebug() << output << endl;
```

and my script.py

```
import sys
print("Hello world!")
```

The strange thing is when I change "python script.py" to "ping google.com" it's working like a charm. I checked it also on my cmd, but it seems that my Python installation is also good. 
Where I'm doing it wrong?

[EDIT 1]
echo %PATH%

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;C:\NVPACK\gradle-2.9\bin;C:\NVPACK\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\NVPACK\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r12b;C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support;C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools;C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Users\Micha?\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Comment: Don't you mean QString output = process.readAllStandardOutput(); ?

Comment: its not working too :( Im getting output like below
""

Comment: Are you on linux? `python` can be also `python2`, try `python3` instead.

Comment: Im on Windows 8.1. I use QtCreator with msvc2013 64bit

Comment: Therefore, use `C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe ` instead.

Comment: Or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe` on a 64bit system.

Comment: @Tatarinho. What is the output of `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: It's tough to say where this is failing, since the code contains no error checking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend your `PATH` environment variable.

If you used an official installer and accepted the default install location, python will probably be in e.g. `C:/Python27`, `C:/Python35`, etc. So you need to add these paths, and probably also e.g. `C:/Python27/Scripts`.

See: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/q/284342).

Comment: what about if I'm running script with full path to Python? 
 QStringList params;
    params << "script.py";
    QString exe = "C:\Python27\python.exe";
    process.start(exe, params);

Comment: Are you saying you get no output when you use the full path? What is the output of: `qDebug() << process.errorString();`?